# Azure Cloud Web Role + AspNetCompiler?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, aspnet-compiler

Has anyone successfully integrated the AspNetCompiler task/target with Azure Cloud Web Role packages (cspkg) files?

I've not been able to figure out how or at which step to perform the compilation so my Azure Web Role is in a fully compiled state.

TeamCity integration a plus.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to do this in a more or less reliable way (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12511368/57428)) and it looks like the best bet is to invoke in-place precompilation from inside role `OnStart()` by using [ClientBuildManager.PrecompileApplication()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620704/57428). This wastes some time for each startup - at least 10 seconds for the simplest site under ASP.NET 4.0 (I haven't tried later versions but I've heard they might have much faster precompilation).

Comment: Thanks. I gave this a go briefly but didn't notice a comparative speed-up to using the aspnet_compiler tool on the project directly.

Comment: @Andrew: This thing just runs aspnet_compiler under the hood so it's unlikely to give any speed-up compared to that.